PCA time series Index in R: Score Plot Doesn't Match Expected Index
I'm working on creating a PCA Index in R to understand how it works. I've used 'make up' data for this purpose. However, when I plot the scores of the first component, the results are not as expected. Specifically, the score plot shows that the index performs poorly in the first year and then rapidly improves over time, which is the opposite of what I intended.
pca <- prcomp(data, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE)
score <- scale(data) %*% pca$rotation[, 1]
plot(score)

I'm trying to figure out what I might be doing wrong or how I can interpret the results better. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated."

data is here
